# count grade inside sublist of dictionary which is inside a list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

i am fairly new to python, and i am learning how to loop through list, dictionaries tuples et...
i made up this list with dictionaries and i want to know how to loop through the each dictionary and count the grades and add the sum of the grades together to know the total.
i have added my loop after the dictionary.

````
    students = [
        {
            'first_name': 'Carlos',
            'last_name': 'Santiago',
            'class':'French',
            'grades': [
                'A',
                'B+',
                'C'
            ]
        },
        {
            'first_name': 'Dana',
            'last_name': 'Lynn',
            'class':'Spanish',
            'grades': [
                'D',
                'A+',
                'A',
                'B'
            ]
        },
        {
            'first_name': 'Fin',
            'last_name': 'leroy',
            'class':'Math',
            'grades': [
                'B',
                'B+',
                'A',
                'A+',
                'B'
            ]
        }
    ]```



    ```sum =0
       for i in students:
         if i =='grades':
           for v in students['grades']:
            sum+=v
            print(sum)```
````

Comment: okay so i need to clarify what i need to be done, so what i need is to count how many elements are in the sublists of the dictionaries with the key='grades'.  like at the end i would want to have the total count of elements in all the sublists  together

Comment: what i've done so far was this but it only outputs the element count of each sublist and i want the total of all of them

```for student in students:
    total = len(student['grades'])
    print(total)```

Comment: okay i've solved it. Thank you for everyone ! ```total_grades=0
for student in students:
    total = len(student['grades'])
    total_grades+=total
    print(total_grades)```

Answer (score 0):

- use enumerate to loop through the elements of your list
- make sure to reset the sum for every student inside the loop

```
for student in enumerate(students):
    sum = 0
    list_of_grades = student[1]['grades']
    for grade in list_of_grades:
        *Your code to add the grades goes here*
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the sum (concatenation in your case) of the grades of each student :

```
for student in students:
    sum = ''.join(student['grades'])
    print(sum)
```

Example output :

```
AB+C
```

summing strings concatenates them.

If you change `grades` to be something like :

```
'grades': [ 5, 7, 10, 3]
```

Then :

```
for student in students:
    sum = sum(student['grades'])
    print(sum)
```

Outputs : `25`

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to avoid using built-in function names (e.g., sum) as your object name.

Second, I assume you meant to get the sum of integers or floats. So I replaced your string grades with integers.

```
students_new = [
    {
        'first_name': 'Carlos',
        'last_name': 'Santiago',
        'class':'French',
        'grades': [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        'first_name': 'Dana',
        'last_name': 'Lynn',
        'class':'Spanish',
        'grades': [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        'first_name': 'Fin',
        'last_name': 'leroy',
        'class':'Math',
        'grades': [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        ]
    }
]

total=0
for i in students_new:
    i_sum = sum(i['grades'])
    print(i['last_name'], i['class'], 'grade:', i_sum)
    total+=i_sum
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this can simply be done in a one liner using list comprehension en `value_counts`:

```
pd.Series([g for l in [rec['grades'] for rec in students] for g in l]).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
A     3
B     3
B+    2
A+    2
C     1
D     1
dtype: int64
```